# Pasting in command mode or search mode (/) in vim

Tags: vim

Are there special key bindings for pasting in command mode or search mode in vim. I would be really helpful in pasting long command or search strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To search on text you have in buffer `a`, you can do the following:

```
/^Ra
```

where `^R` is `Control-R`.

Comment: thanks, that works infact it works in insert mode and command mode also